# How to implement multiple photo picker in Angular-Formly?

Tags: angular-formly

I'm trying to implement a custom template to allow for selection of image(s) to upload. After the user selects an image this is shown in a horizontal scroller on the form. The model field is an array of image filenames selected.

The functionality works perfectly in a normal form, but when converted into Angular-Formly, the image selection process works, the model field (array) gets updated, but the NG-REPEAT (horizontal scroller) does not show the images in the array.

The template I'm trying to make work is:

```
<!-- IMAGE HORIZONTAL SCROLLER AND INPUT -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="imagePicker.html">
 <ion-item class="item-icon-right">
    <i class="icon ion-images" ng-click="to.onclick(model,options)"></i>
      <ion-scroll direction="x" style="height:200px; min-height: 200px; overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap;">
          <img ng-repeat="image in model[options.key]" ng-src="{{urlForImage(image)}}" style="height:100px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;"/>
      </ion-scroll>
  </ion-item>
</script>
<!-- END OF IMAGE HORIZONTAL SCROLLER AND INPUT -->
```

Comment: I got it resolved :) The problem was the ng-src="{{urlForImage(image)}}". For some reason the call does not get through. So I call this while storing the value in the array and made ng-src="{{ image }}" and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself.  The problem was

```
ng-src="{{urlForImage(image)}}"
```

For some reason the call does not get through. So I call this while storing the value in the array and changed it to

```
ng-src="{{ image }}"
```

Now it works.